# Number of Attribute Content

Tags: jquery

How can I count items in a custom attribute using javascript or jquery?

Like in

```
<div case="'cond_1' 'cond_2' 'cond_3'">
  // Content
</div>
```

There are 3 items in "case" attribute. Is there a way to count those items?

Thanks

Comment: get attribute value, split it, and get count.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var count = $('div').attr('data-case').split(" ").length;

console.log(count)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-case="'cond_1' 'cond_2' 'cond_3'">
  // Content
</div>
```

1. Use `data-*` as case only is not a valid attr
2. Use split and then use length to get the count of the attr

Comment: @CanSerinyel happy coding